# FreeTDS Bad token from the server (SQL Server)

Tags: sql-server, ruby-on-rails, activerecord, freetds

Today we had a lot more activity than normal between our Ruby on Rails application and our remote legacy [SQL Server 2005](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/History_of_Microsoft_SQL_Server#SQL_Server_2005) database, and we started getting the error below intermittently. What is is? How can I prevent it (besides avoiding the situation, which we're working on)?

#### Error Message:

> ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: DBI::DatabaseError: 08S01 (20020) [unixODBC][FreeTDS][SQL Server]
> Bad token from the server: Datastream processing out of sync: SELECT * FROM [marketing] WHERE ([marketing].[contact_id] = 832085)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[This Microsoft article](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/109787) says:

> Often caused by an abruptly terminated network connection, which causes a damaged Tabular Data Stream token to be read by the client.

Was the server network bound? I have no experience with SQL Server, but does it have a limit on the number of connections you can make?

Answer (score 1):

You need to use some sort of connection pooling.

Windows itself (including Windows Server X) will only allow a certain number of socket connections to be created in a given time frame, even if you close them. All others will fail after that.

A connection pool will keep the same sockets open, avoiding the problem. Also, new connections are real slow.

Comment: What is *"Windows Server X"*?

Answer (score -1):

Add the following to your script; the first statement you run:

```
SET NO_BROWSETABLE OFF
```